# Calcular salário anual

Tags: java, matemática

• Modele um funcionário. Ele deve ter o nome do funcionário (`String`), o departamento onde trabalha (`String`), seu salário (`double`), a data de entrada no banco (`String`) e seu RG (`String`).

• Crie um método `recebeAumento(double percentual)` que aumenta o salario do funcionário de acordo com o parâmetro passado como argumento. Crie também um método `calculaGanhoAnual`, que não recebe parâmetro algum, devolvendo o valor do salário anual considerando 13º e férias.

Meu rascunho (estou tentando chamar a função calcula para o ganho anual, mas nem isso consigo).

```
package funcionario;

public class Funcionario {
    String nome, dep, banco, RG;
    double sal, novosal;

    void recebe(double aumento){
        double recebeAumento = this.sal + aumento;
        this.sal = recebeAumento;
    }
    public static double calcula(){
         sal * 12;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Funcionario f1;
        f1 = new Funcionario();
        f1.nome = "João";
        f1.dep = "Defesa";        
        f1.banco = "Banco do Brasil S.A";
        f1.RG = "798956-5";
        f1.sal = 27000.0;
        f1.recebe(2000);

        System.out.println("Nome: " + f1.nome + "\nDepartamento: " + f1.dep + "\nBanco: " + f1.banco + "\nRG: " + f1.RG + "\nSalário: " + f1.sal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está perto. Na verdade precisa reler o enunciado, ele diz até os nomes dos métodos que devem ser criados.

Não tem muito porque o método ser estático ali. Tem erros de sintaxe. Também tem campo que não parece ser necessário.

A enunciado não é bom, interpretei o cálculo como eu quis.

Tem outros problemas que para um exercício básico não importa, mas em código real não é assim que se codifica.

```
class Funcionario {
    String nome, dep, banco, RG;
    double salario;

    void recebeAumento(double percentual) {
        salario += salario / 100 * percentual;
    }
    public double calculaGanhoAnual() {
         return salario * 13 + salario / 3;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Funcionario f1 = new Funcionario();
        f1.nome = "João";
        f1.dep = "Defesa";        
        f1.banco = "Banco do Brasil S.A";
        f1.RG = "798956-5";
        f1.salario = 27000.0;
        f1.recebeAumento(2000);
        System.out.println("Nome: " + f1.nome + "\nDepartamento: " + f1.dep + "\nBanco: " + f1.banco + "\nRG: " + f1.RG + "\nSalário Anual: " + f1.calculaGanhoAnual());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/BZ7qOA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dcltvdla-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/CalcSalary.java).